# How to replace comma with space in text file using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in a text file (input.jpg). I want to replace the comma with the space and align the data in one line.Please see the output text file (output.jpg).

how to do this in VBA. 
Please help me.

[input data]
[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a teach me to code site.  If you have code that does not work then please post it in you original post using [edit] and explain exactly where the error is occurring.

Comment: If you are using Windows.  PowerShell may be a better fit to do this: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2008/01/17/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-replace-characters-in-a-text-file/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Sub foo()
Dim objFSO
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objTS 'define a TextStream object
Dim strContents As String
Dim fileSpec As String

fileSpec = "C:\Test.txt" 'change the path to whatever yours ought to be
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForReading)

Do While Not objTS.AtEndOfStream
    strContents = strContents & " " & objTS.ReadLine 'Read line by line and store all lines in strContents
Loop

strContents = Replace(strContents, ",", " ")
objTS.Close

Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForWriting)
objTS.Write strContents
objTS.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Xabier. it is working.

Comment: If the data is in multiple lines in text file, how to arrange it in a single line. for ex:  "Datastart 19A 56 1 0x1112 0x1314 0x1516 0x1718 0x1920 0x2122 0x2324 0x2526 0x2728 0x2930 
                  0x3132 0x3334 0x3536 0x3738 0x3940 0x4142 0x4344 0x4546 0x4748 0x4950 
                  0x5152 0x5354 0x5556 0x5758 0x5960 0x6162 0x6364 0x6566"  . How we can arrange this text in single line.

Comment: @chandrashekar I've updated my answer to put all the lines into a single line..